# Getting a list of time zones names with moment-timezone within AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timezone, momentjs, single-page-application

I have an AngularJS based SPA and I am trying to get a list of time zones names with moment-timezone within AngularJS controller.

- This is the error I am getting when I am importing it: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. at addZone (moment-timezone.js:385)"
- MomentJS by itself is working just fine i.e Importing moment (not moment-timezone)
- I would prefer to use pure Moment over any wrapping around it like angular-moment
- Running it on chrome browser

Why that error might happen? 
Can you provide a small code sample that works?

Update (I am adding the code):

```
'use strict';
import moment from 'moment'; // works
import momentTZ from 'moment-timezone'; // this breaks it

export default class RequestCtrl {
    constructor() { 
        console.log(moment()); //works
        //console.log(momentTZ.tz.names());
        //console.log(moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles').format());}
```

[image]

In order to test moment-timezone in isolation, i used JSFiddle. This is a screenshot of where TZ is *working with angularJS*. Unfortunately, it still breaks in my project
[image]

Comment: *Can you provide a small code sample that works?* - can you provide a sample that *doesn't* work? It's asker's responsibility to provide all necessary information on the problem. Otherwise the question is considered off-topic and can be closed. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @estus updated with the requested info

Comment: Your question is still not well constructed. Lay out the problem before the sharing the code. Beyond the ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) advice, you also need to start by stating the question in a way that focuses on what gap remains _after_ your research. Describe [step like these](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-debug-any-problem-ac6f8a867fae) that you have done thus far, for code, conditions, and errors. State 'obvious' context that you already know, [so that people understand what you have tried](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looking to get list of all time zones, you have to import `moment-timezone` module.

You can import and use `moment-timezone` module similar to how we do other modules.

Within that we can get all list of timezones using `moment.tz.names()`

Make sure, you will have **json loader** in your webpack config. Looks like moment timezone module needs this.

Comment: Thanks @G_S. I added the code now. I do import moment  timezone. Any idea why this breaks?

Comment: It still breaks? Isnt it momentTZ().tz.names() in your case?

Comment: It is. I will update. Nonetheless, I am not even getting there. The moment (LOL) I import 'moment-timezone' it breaks.

Comment: i hope you did an npm i for moment-timezone (which i generally forget to do). Once update object and let us know if it still breaks

Comment: Ok. So as per your updated code, moment time zone is working. As per console you are getting names. Right?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiggity. I updated my question. It is working in JSFiddle but still breaks in my project. So I am still in square one...

Comment: Is it possible to create a code snippet for us to check whats causing the issue? There should be something else that might be causing the issue

Comment: this is the way I installed it: 'npm install moment-timezone'. https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/. Should I have installed TZ in a different way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165437/discussion-between-g-s-and-rotem-varon).